# ENOENT system.log while running ionic emulate ios

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I am following this guide: http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/

Once I get to `ionic emulate ios` I get

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/$USERNAME/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/DCB9BBDE-FFEC-43CD-B88E-FFFB6CBF0045/system.log'

I tried what other people did to solve their problem, like

- `chown` your $HOME to yourself
- remove `platforms` folder
- remove XCode and install again

But none of this solved my problem.

I am on OSX El Capitan, using node v4.3.1 installed with nave (might this be an issue?).

I've tried with a fresh new project and got this

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/$USER/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/FF5BE4A0-C42E-4C35-884F-21EFC514A846/system.log'
>   Error code 1 for command: ios-sim with args: launch,/Users/$USER/workspace/myApp/platforms/ios/build/emulator/myApp.app,--devicetypeid,com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6,--stderr,/Users/$USER/workspace/myApp/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--stdout,/Users/$USER/workspace/myApp/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--exit
>   Error: /Users/$USER/workspace/myApp/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2

Thank you in advance

Comment: I "solved" using XCode and not the command line tools...

Answer (score 0):

Hi please see my answer to the following question:

[ionic emulate ios (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=163)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41745201/ionic-emulate-ios-domain-com-apple-coresimulator-simerror-code-163/42573650#42573650)

After this, I tried:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config
```

in terminal and was able to run the app in a simulator