# ionic emulate ios (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=163)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ionic-framework, simulate

I am trying to simulate a project with ionic using the command `ionic emulate ios`. I have installed xcode last version on mac Sierra. But no work. this is the error:

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

No target specified for emulator. Deploying to iPhone-SE, 10.2 simulator


An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=163):
Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown

An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=163):
Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/var/root/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/4A052961-F773-4156-9D6C-76F137CC761B/system.log'
```

I found this solution(https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/66665) but no work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/

Open a Project within Xcode
Cordova for iOS projects can be opened in Xcode. This can be useful if you wish to use Xcode built in debugging/profiling tools or if you are developing iOS plugins. Please note that when opening your project in Xcode, it is recommended that you do NOT edit your code in the IDE. This will edit the code in the platforms folder of your project (not www), and changes are liable to be overwritten. Instead, edit the www folder and copy over your changes by running cordova build.

Plugin developers wishing to edit their native code in the IDE should use the --link flag when adding their plugin to the project via cordova plugin add. This will link the files so that changes to the plugin files in the platforms folder are reflected in your plugin's source folder (and vice versa).

Once the ios platform is added to your project and built using cordova build, you can open it from within Xcode. Double-click to open the ${PROJECT_NAME}/platforms/ios/${PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj file. The screen should look like this:

https://cordova.apache.org/static/img/guide/platforms/ios/helloworld_project.png

Then follow the instructions to deploy to a simulator:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/#deploying-to-simulator

You will be able to see errors more clearly.
In my case it was the problem of an unmatched resource file. I simply deleted it.

After this, I tried:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config
```

in terminal and was able to run the app in a simulator